# Point Anaconda to multiple locations for source files

Tags: anaconda, conda

Working in an offline Windows 10 environment where I have available a local mirror of conda-forge and an installation of Anaconda3. I need to create an environment with packages of which some are only to be found in conda-forge mirror and some only in local Anaconda3 `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs` folder. Note that the latter is **not** a subset of the former (e.g. `scipy`).

The problem is when I create an environment from an `environment.yml` that includes packages from both groups, then it fails because `conda create --name test --file environment.yml` seems to be only searching the channel. On the other hand `conda create --name test --offline --file environment.yml` is only looking in the above referenced `pkgs` folder.

How can I point `conda create` to both repositories?

Comment: Working with Anaconda in an offline environment has been painful. In this instance, I ended up manually selecting all packages and creating a custom channel to which I direct the `conda create` command using the respective flag.